# Can Apache generate W3C extended format access logs, identical to IIS?

Tags: apache-2.2

Is is possible to configure Apache to reliably generate access logs in W3C extended format idential to that generated by IIS? I can't seem to track down a detailed description of specifics like delimiters, field formats, etc. No doubt there is an apache log format string that can do it, but I don't have enough info to create or even know for sure if it can write the data in the correct format.

I am using a web access log analyzer (SmarterStats) that does not support custom log file formats - it only supports Common Log Format, or W3C extended format. Unfortunately CLF has only very limited data, so doesn't allow particularly interesting analysis.

Comment: what OS are you running Apache on? I ask because depending on OS, there may be a tool that can help you transform your output to be more in line with what you're looking for.

Comment: It's running on RHEL, but I could do some post-processing of the logs if need be.

Answer (score 3):

The [W3C Extended Log File Format](http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-logfile.html) lets you define a set of fields in metadata at the top of the log. The [defaults for IIS 6](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/ffdd7079-47be-4277-921f-7a3a6e610dcb.mspx?mfr=true) seem to be:

```
#Fields: date time c-ip cs-username s-ip s-port cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query sc-status cs(User-Agent)
```

You should check your IIS log to see that this is the case (and what your parser expects) - look for the `#Fields` line at the top.

You can generate an Apache log in this format using a `LogFormat` line something like this:

```
LogFormat "%{%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}t %a %u %A %p %m %U %q %>s \"%{User-agent}i\"" w3c_extended
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/extended_access_log w3c_extended
```

(I can't test this at present: please edit the post or comment if you try it).

Check [Apache's custom log formats](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_log_config.html#formats) to see how I derived that.

Comment: This is what I would have done, but it turns out that SmarterStats requires the header/metadata at the top of the log like IIS produces. Back to the drawing board...

Answer (score 0):

There is this sourceforge [project](http://logw3c.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Last updated 2001; would be a bit scared to use that!

Comment: Nice find, but with over a decade since the code was last updated... Would be a good place to start though, if I need to go the route of writing a custom logging module.

Comment: Code that doesn't need to be updated, isn't updated.  Code has no Best-before date; you need to inspect the code with your eyes instead of a raised nose!